# How to add an easing transition effect to a function in pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, transition

I have a specific page (a div that is inside other divs inside the window) used to create a new user. It is a form with first name, last name... input fields. I'm using an EventListener that targets the input element on click. Then I have a function goToPos that will define the top of the specific page(div) to define the absolute position and scroll to where I want the input element to be positioned (top - 80px). This is working perfectly.

However, I'm trying to add an easing transition effect to smooth the repositioning when clicking through the different inputs (like CSS provides through transition: `all .5s ease-in-out;`, for example), but I can't seem to figure out how I can add this smooth transition effect (and solely to this function or specific eventListener, not as a general behaviour) as I can only use pure JavaScript.

Please see the code below:

```
function goToPos(target) {
    document.getElementById('center1').parentElement.scrollTop = 0;
    var rect = target.getBoundingClientRect();
    document.getElementById('center1').parentElement.scrollTop = rect.top - 80;
}

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement
    goToPos(target);
}, false);
```

Comment: scrollTop is not even a CSS property, so you can not transition it using CSS. Use .animate

Comment: why not jQuery? https://jquery.com/. You can use .animate({top:-80}) like @CBroe said.

Comment: Element.animate is badly supported cross browsers and Jquery is an overkill just for an ease function.